# Software for analysing SEM or TEM images

Tags: resource-recommendations, material-science, software, nanoscience, microscopy

I am looking for a software to analyse [SEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_electron_microscope) and [TEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_electron_microscopy) images of some [PLD experiments](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=PLD+experiments) because I want to characterize the samples, like calculate the concentration of nanoparticles, size, and do some statistics.
Does someone know any software to perform these tasks?

Comment: [Software recommendation questions are generally off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/should-we-allow-software-questions-take-3)

Answer (score 1):

You could try [PEBBLES](http://pebbles.istm.cnr.it/) which is freeware AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

[WSxM](http://wsxmsolutions.com/) is free and does this sort of statistics using the "flood" tool.